# how to define multiple languages in html 4

Tags: php, html

I want to build my website in Hebrew lang.

When I write

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

in the title the labels are looks good but the letters from the DB are all question mark - "????"

When I write

```
<meta charset="windows-1255">
```

letters from DB are OK but all labels are "???".

BTW - I'm also use this code after connecting to the DB:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'hebrew'");

setlocale(LC_ALL, 'he');
```

how can I fix that?

Comment: This is about character encodings, not about languages.

Answer (score 0):

You must tell your DB connection to work in UTF-8, try:

```
mysql_query( 'SET NAMES utf8' );
```

Do this right after you create your MySQL connection. And keep your pages in UTF-8.

Also if you are starting a new project, you really should use the `mysqli_*` functions instead of `mysql_*`

Comment: should I use "mysqli_" all the time? for instance - "$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM `users_setup` WHERE  (`userID` = '$userID')");"
?

Comment: Be aware that you cannot simply replace mysql_ in your code with mysqli_. Fix your code first and then read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php/14112684#14112684